# Is there a way to set GWT to include style names in the compiled names?

Tags: gwt, cssresource

I use CssResource extensively, and now my generated html is full of GWXSHFKADAish class names.  I get all of the advantages of that, but for debugging it'd be helpful to add a flag that would turn `.selected` into `GWXSTY_selected`.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty"/>
```

in your .gwt.xml file, then the resulting class names will contain the original class name.